# Can't link css to jsp (Spring mvc)

Tags: java, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I am struggling with spring mvc file structure.

I am able to display an image ressource in a jsp **but not to link a css** to it, even if they are at the same location !

Here is my **file structure** :

```
/src
 /main
   /resources
   /webapps
      /resources
          main.css
          logo.png
      /views
          somePage.jsp
      /WEB-INF
         web.xml
         dispatcher-servlet.xml
         ....
```

Here is what I have in my **dispatcher** :

```
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
     </bean>

  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

And in my **somePage.jsp**  :

```
 <img src="<c:url value="/resources/logo.png" />" alt="blabla" />

 <link href="<c:url value="/resources/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet" />

 ...
```

The **image load correctly** but **not the css**...

Note : I have the following message in eclipse : : "invalid location of tag (link). " about the css link...

If you have any idea, thank you by advance !

Comment: I explained that /resources/logo.png works, the problem is the css that does not load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seems to be a cache issue.

I just delete my chrome cache and my css appeared.

When I compiled the first time, my css was empty and I filled it later.
It seems that even after editing it and re-running the project the css state ,wasn't refreshed.

chrome probably kept my css state as empty and didn't detect the update .. weird.

Answer (score 0):

You add some code. like this.

Your servelet-context.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Your jsp

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="<%=request.getContextPath()%>"></c:set>


<link href="${contextPath}/resources/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```